# RESOURCE specifications and tracking of agent

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I need to solve a problem, which due to my lack of Java training I can't solve. What is the code to write to trace the agent who took a resource?
Let me explain better...I have a series of rooms, each agent who enters the structure takes a room which he keeps for his entire stay, and I would like to see in real-time, which rooms are occupied and by which agent. How can I do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply save the resource seized to the agent and vice versa using variables, in the seize block.

Here is a simple example

I have  a Person and a RoomResource agent, each with a variable of the other's type.

[image]

In this very simple flow chart with a source that creates persons, and a seize connected to a resource pool of RoomResource agents, and the resource units live in a population called `roomResource`.

[image]

You simply specify the following in the seize block

```
agent.room = unit;
unit.agent = agent;
```

[image]

You will see that agent represents the agent in the block, and unit represents the unit being seized from the resource pool

[image]

Now you can visually use this for your agents

[image]

Now you can see what Person occupies which room and which room is used for each person by accessing the variable

Comment: thank you very much for your reply!
Once I have displayed the person occupying the room, can I access their variables?

Comment: Yes - you can access the person and then all their variables and perhaps have it displayed on the animation in the room.