# how can i keep the resource name in the entity agent in anylogic?

Tags: java, anylogic

how can I release specific resource in Anylogic?
in my process I have a seize block which seizes 3 alternative resources (according to their availability).
near the end I need to release one of the potential resources in the release block, according the resource which was seized.
what do I have to do in order to know which resource was seized and how do I release it?
I can't use the service block because the process constrains.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the Seize block and release block, and not the combined service block.

[image]

You can then use the options provided in the release block

[image]

You can read more in the help file

https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/release.html

You might need to seize your resources in specific seize blocks or make use of the dynamic parameters in the release blocks if you want to execute with more control

Comment: i want to make sure that I released the specific resource that was seized.

Comment: In this case I have 3 alternative resources.
All the three supposed to be seized during the running simulation and attached to the agent (the product) until the last process (the model include 3 process) and then to be released.what do I have to do in order to know which resource was seized and how do I release it?

Comment: The release block will do all of this for you - check the options in the screenshot I posted. Try it. I will work, it is standard AnyLogic functionality

Comment: thaks. what do i have to do to trace the quantity of uses for each resource unit?

Comment: You can check this answer for how to save the specific resource sized to both the resource and the agent and then you can do with it what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68632841/4019094

Comment: how should i separate the counts for each unit of resource?
now, it counts the uses for all three together

Comment: If I understanding your question, it sounds that is because they are used together. But this sounds like a new question.. do you mind asking a new question on SO? If I answer was the solution to your original question, please accept it.

Comment: no problem i will ask at as new question .
thank you very much

Comment: @NaveHelfand Remember to accept my answer if you found it helpful, and upvote if you think it deserving ;-)